# Do I still need to worry about LegacyExchangeDN when creating a dist group in Exchange 2007?

Tags: exchange-2007

I'm extremely new to Exhange and have a programming task to create distribution groups.

The method I am using is

```
public GroupPrincipal CreateDistributionGroup(string groupName, string displayName, string description, GroupScope groupScope, 
            string emailAddress, string exchangeDN)
        {
            GroupPrincipal distGrp = this.CreateGroup(groupName, description, groupScope, false);

            this.SetGroupAttribute(distGrp, GroupAttribute.MailNickName, groupName);
            this.SetGroupAttribute(distGrp, GroupAttribute.DisplayName, displayName);
            this.SetGroupAttribute(distGrp, GroupAttribute.ReportToOriginator, true);
            this.SetGroupAttribute(distGrp, GroupAttribute.Mail, emailAddress);
            this.SetGroupArrayAttribute(distGrp, GroupAttribute.ProxyAddresses, "SMTP:" + emailAddress);
            this.SetGroupAttribute(distGrp, GroupAttribute.LegacyExchangeDN, exchangeDN);
            this.SetGroupAttribute(distGrp, GroupAttribute.MsExchRecipientDisplayType, 1);

            return distGrp;
        }
```

Notice that one attribute that gets set is the LegacyExchangeDN. Can I safely ignore this in Exchange 2007, or is it still required?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LegacyExchangeDN is used by Outlook2000 clients (IIRC) and for other Outlook clients that cached a group *before Exch 2007 was in place*. Which is to say, if you don't have 11 year old Outlook running around, you shouldn't need to set that for new groups.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. I ignored that property and the group creation went through just fine.